# Accessing bit data of DwmRegisterThumbnail

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have been playing around with the Windows DWM APIs to see if I can capture external windows with them.  I have made a small C++ program which creates a window, grabs an external HWND, links the external HWND to my window, and successfully renders the external data.  The API works great in this situation.

What I'm trying to figure out now is whether or not I can capture the bit data which being rendered into my own window.  I figured since I have ownership of this window there should be a way.

## My Goals

To capture the DWM rendered content in my own window into a bitmap.  This should work regardless of whether my window is in the *foreground* or *background*.

## My Test Case

In my test case I have a youtube video playing in my external window.  I put it in the background and allow the video to render into my application's window in the foreground.  From there I try the methods below to capture the content of my window.

## Capture Methods Attempted

### BitBlt

I've tried to use BitBlt to capture the windows content into a bitmap.  Whenever I try this though, I simply end up with title bar of my window and none of the DWM thumbnail content.
   *However*, if instead of getting a DC for my window, I get a DC for the entire screen and grab the coordinates of my window, I am able to get the DWM rendered content.  But if the window is in the background, obviously I don't get what I want.

### PrintWindow

PrintWindow fails for me as well.  I get similar results to BitBlt, my windows title bar but nothing in the content area.

## My Question

Is there any reliable way to get the bit data from the DWM APIs?  Could I do something on WM_PAINT/WM_PRINT to capture this?